# Can not import fastai [WinError 126] The specified module could not be foun

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pytorch, fast-ai

Firstly I run the following command: `conda install -c pytorch -c fastai fastai`. After finishing `install`. I import this:

```
from fastai.imports import *
```

I got an `error` like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\acer\Desktop\Reddit Bot\demo.py", line 70, in <module>
    from fastai.imports import *

  File "C:\Users\acer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastai\imports\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .torch import *

  File "C:\Users\acer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastai\imports\torch.py", line 1, in <module>
    import torch, torch.nn.functional as F

  File "C:\Users\acer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    ctypes.CDLL(dll)

  File "C:\Users\acer\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

I watch some post on `stackoverflow` but can't solve this. How can I solve this? Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

This probably happened if you, like me - are using a machine without a NVIDIA GPU card. `conda install -c pytorch -c fastai fastai` will install a version that uses the GPU.

To resolve this, I uninstalled pytorch and then conda installed the CPU version using `conda install pytorch torchvision cpuonly -c pytorch.` It worked for me! You can check the pytorch installation guide on the official [website](https://pytorch.org/) :)

Comment: @HumayunAhmadRajib that's unfortunate! What error are you getting? Maybe try creating a completely new virtual environment and installing only fastai and pytorch in it? Otherwise, the other package versions might be clashing and causing a dependency problem.